# Congruence of certain numbers mod a large prime

Tags: group-theory, congruences

I have a set of small prime numbers $S = \{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}$.

By multiplying those I can form other numbers, by assigning to each element of the set an exponent of $0$ or $1$, so that I can form $2^{10}$ different numbers in total--because there are ten elements in the set. So let's say I call the set of all such numbers $T$.

I also have a (large) prime, around $10^6$, which I call $p$.

Let's call the set of numbers in $T$, reduced $\bmod p$, $T_p$. Are all elements of $T_p$ different, as is the case for $T$? If yes, how would one prove that? If not, please give an example.

This is not an exercise, so I have no reference. The answer might be positive or negative, but I need some input to find out. :)
(Also, if anyone can word the title a bit better that I have, please do provide suggestions)

Comment: So you are asking if there are distinct subsets of S whose products are congruent  mod p?

Comment: Yes that's it. I figured I'd make another set to make it clearer, but that's the same thing.

Comment: Do you have a specific $p$ in mind?  It may well depend on which $p$ you choose.

Comment: The product of all of these is $6,469,693,230$.  Many of the products will be smaller than your $p$ and we know they are distinct.  As you delete factors you will fall down towards $10^6$ quickly, so it seems clear that for most primes around $10^6$ there will not be a match mod $p$.

Comment: Yes @RossMillikan, I was wondering though if it was the case that no match exists.

Comment: @Qudit, no, I have a dozen of such primes, so I was looking for something general

Comment: I am sure that you can find a $p$ such that no match exists-there just aren't enough tries.  It has also been shown that there is at least one  $p$ such that a match exists.  Would that solve your question? $2^10$ is a small number. It would be easy to list all the products and try primes until you find one that fits your requirement.

Comment: I don't really *need* the primes to fulfill that "no-match" rule---just being close enough is okay, although, I wanted to be able to make a theoretical observation for completeness. Also, the primes I have need to fulfill other rules as well that take quite some time to verify. But, I'd be interested in the proof you mention.

Answer (score 1):

From SAGE:
sage: factor$(2*3*5*7*11*17*19*23*29 -13)$

$67 * 7427891$

So the prime number above exceeding 7 million divides the difference between 13 and the product of the nine prime numbers < 30 after excluding 13.